# Element disappears when I add an {% include %} tag inside my for loop

Tags: python, django

Here's my template code for my comment queryset:

```
{% block comments %}
{% load el_pagination_tags %}
    {% paginate 10 comment_list %}
        {% for i in comment_list %}
            <div class='comment_div'>
                <div class="left_comment_div">
                    <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% include 'comment/comments.html' with comment_list=i.replies.all %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% show_more %}  
{% endblock %}
```

I'm using [django el pagination](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html#quickstart) to implement ajax pagination. On the 3rd line you can see I initially load 10 comments. With this package, comes a `{% show_more %}` [element I can add](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags_reference.html#show-more) which, when clicked, will load the rest of the comments.

However, this `{% show_more %}`element disapears for some reason when I add `{% include 'comment/comments.html' with comment_list=i.replies.all %}`. For context, this `include` tag shows the replies for the current comment in the for loop.

Does anyone have any idea why this include tag affects the `{% show_more %}` element?

**EDIT:** Below is the relevent code for displaying `show_more` [Github Source](https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination/blob/develop/el_pagination/templatetags/el_pagination_tags.py#L356)

**el_pagination_tags.py**

```
# show the template only if there is a next page
if page.has_next():
    print('Has next') #doesn't print
    request = context['request']
    page_number = page.next_page_number()
    # Generate the querystring.
    querystring_key = data['querystring_key']
    querystring = utils.get_querystring_for_page(
        request, page_number, querystring_key,
        default_number=data['default_number'])
    return {
        'label': label,
        'loading': loading,
        'class_name': class_name,
        'path': iri_to_uri(data['override_path'] or request.path),
        'querystring': querystring,
        'querystring_key': querystring_key,
        'request': request,
    }
# No next page, nothing to see.
print('No next') #prints for every comment (e.g. 20 times when 20 comments)
return {}
```

Can I change something in the above code to possibly make it work, or atleast debug further to help me find more about the problem? Help appreciated.

Comment: Is it there when you inspect the page ?

Comment: No it's not there when I inspect

Comment: Might help to also paste the content of `comment/comments.html`. There is no error in the python console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding an `if` statement for my `include` tag like this:

```
        {% if i.replies.all %}
            {% include 'comment/comments.html' with comment_list=i.replies.all %}
        {% else %}
```

which only adds the include tag if that comment has 1 or more replies. Previously it would add an empty queryset if there were no replies, causing errors in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably consuming/changing variables in the included template that influence the behavior of `show_more`.

To debug you could either run via debugger and step into the show_more templatetag code or add print statements into that code (it's python so that works just fine).

The relevant code is in django-el-pagination/el_pagination/templatetags/el_pagination_tags.py#330 (https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination):

```
# This template tag could raise a PaginationError: you have to call
# *paginate* or *lazy_paginate* before including the showmore template.
data = utils.get_data_from_context(context)
page = data['page']
# show the template only if there is a next page
if page.has_next():
    request = context['request']
    page_number = page.next_page_number()
    # Generate the querystring.
    querystring_key = data['querystring_key']
    querystring = utils.get_querystring_for_page(
        request, page_number, querystring_key,
        default_number=data['default_number'])
    return {
        'label': label,
        'loading': loading,
        'class_name': class_name,
        'path': iri_to_uri(data['override_path'] or request.path),
        'querystring': querystring,
        'querystring_key': querystring_key,
        'request': request,
    }
# No next page, nothing to see.
return {}
```

`show_more` will be empty if either:

- `page` has reached the last iteration
- `querystring` is empty (see the template django-el-pagination/el_pagination/templates/el_pagination/show_more.html)

Comment: Can you give any suggestions that I can try for debugging? Either to alter the `show_more()` function or add print statements? I've edited my code if you want to have a look - I'm not sure why `Has next` doesn't even print once, even though all the comments still load. Any idea?

Comment: If it does not reach that print but reaches the `if` then either `page` is `None` or `page.has_next()` is `False`. Maybe the page is somehow lost from the context or overridden with `None` at some point. Compare the context (via `debug` in the template) between the working and the non-working version.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the name here. comment_list to something else.

```
{% include 'comment/comments.html' with replies=i.replies.all %}
```

Comment: Doesn't work (gives this error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
`)

Comment: That could be from a different place. Can you update your question with comments.html code and the error traceback ?