# How to check if a queryset is empty?

Tags: python, django, pagination

Pagination code:

```
try:
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
    print(page.object_list)
```

So the following output is the result of `print(page.object_list)` for my pagination:

```
<QuerySet [<Comment: I can't believe it's happeinig>, <Comment: Just trying to fill up the comments>, <Comment: Another one!>, <Comment: Evenmore noe>, <Comment: Something>, <Comment: Lol>, <Comment: Are comments showing up?>, <Comment: Great for the economy.>, <Comment: honestly>, <Comment: Even though the the onlyEven though the only one to udnertstnaf!>]>
<QuerySet [<Comment: Yeah it's crazy how fast aswell. It's very awesome how it's doing atm. >]>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [<Comment: Sure>, <Comment: No worries>]>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [<Comment: attempt 2!>]>
<QuerySet [<Comment: Attempt 3!>]>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [<Comment: 12>]>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [<Comment: Somewhere?>]>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [<Comment: lol>]>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet [<Comment: 12>]>
<QuerySet []>
```

As you can see I have empty querysets, and these are causing errors in my code. I therefore would like to iterate over these querysets and spot the empty ones. I tried to add this for loop:

```
for i in page.object_list:
    if len(i) < 0:
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError at /news/11/
object of type 'Comment' has no len()
```

Any help appreciated.

**Trying to delete the a queryset if it is empty:**

```
try:
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
    if page.object_list:
        pass
    else:
        page.delete()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError at /news/11/
'CustomPage' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Comment: You should filter your queryset before ever making the paginator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test the QuerySet directly using an *if* clause. This would cause the QuerySet to be evaluated. Empty QuerySets (or empty lists) are *falsy*:

```
page = paginator.page(page_number)
if page.object_list:
    ...
```

If you want to iterate on the QuerySet, there's no need to test for emptiness. Just use the *for* clause:

```
for obj in page.object_list: # empty QuerySet gets zero iterations
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to delete the page in the `else` clause? If you look at my edit I've attempted but not sure how.

Comment: If it's empty, you don't need to delete anything. Python will do the garbage collection for you.

Comment: There definitely are empty ones, which is why It's causing errors in my pagination package. Are you able to have a look at my other question which is related to this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46847282/element-disappears-when-i-add-an-include-tag-inside-my-for-loop The reason that `has_next()` is `False` is because of those empty querysets inbetween. I'll delete this comment soon.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong upstream (prolly in your template). If the queryset is empty, no comments should be shown.

Comment: You're correct, no comments are shown. But in the backend it shows an empty queryset, as you can see in my original post above: `<QuerySet []>`. And this affects the `has_next()` function in my package, which reads `False` because of empty querysets.

Comment: If you're doing this in a loop, you can simply use `continue` to move over to the next `page_number` and avoid performing any operation on the empty QS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158502/discussion-between-zorgan-and-moses-koledoye).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#exists)(emphasis mine)

```
page.object_list.exists()
```

> Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not. This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query.
>
> exists() is useful for searches relating to both object membership in a QuerySet and **to the existence of any objects in a QuerySet, particularly in the context of a large QuerySet**.

Although, it would be much better to filter the queryset before creating the paginator

Answer (score 0):

Another way is :

```
if page.object_list.count() == 0:
  #Empty Result
else:
  #Something
```

Comment: While this would work, if your object_list is large, you would be running a potential expensive query just to check if you should do something with the data. Further, that count method is slower than using func.count on the query. If you really want to check the count, I'd recommend doing something like `.with_entities(func.count("some_col")).scalar()` or similar.